# ARRAYFORMULA with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

In column B are listed IDs of Google Sheets. In column C are listed cells, from which I want to import data.

[Screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxGsS.jpg)

In column D is shown the result of using IMPORTRANGE() by simply dragging it. e.g. for D1 it looks like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(B1;C1)
```

for D2:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(B2;C2)
```

and so on.

In column E I want to display the same result but using ARRAYFORMULA that looks like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(B2:B4,C2:C4))
```

but the function displays only the data from the first spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work when importing data (I think it relates to permissions). You could use something like this, =IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(B5:B7;C5:C7)) and pre-fill the column first, but still there would be the permissions issue. Each new imported sheet needs it's permissions granted by a user.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I solved this problem using a apps script.

Comment: would you share your script ? This seems to be a common issue, and I've been looking for a solution for several hours already ...

Answer (score 2):

People complain about this permissions issue a lot, but it's not hard to solve. What I do is have a sheet which I name "Splash sheet" into which I paste the URLs of the documents I wish to link. To its right is a column headed "permit to connect" which contains IMPORTRANGE formulas importing a single cell from each sheet -- usually a cell containing a confirmation code, number or document name -- on a sheet also named "Splash Sheet." For example,

=IF(B3="enter URL",,CONCATENATE(IMPORTRANGE(B3,"Splash sheet!A1")," ",IMPORTRANGE(B3,"Splash sheet!B1")))

So, when you first connect a spreadsheet via its URL, you get those messages telling you you need to connect, you click the Permit Access, the confirmation code/number/document name appears in the second column, and voilá, your sheets are connected forevermore! Now all your other IMPORTRANGEs referencing that URL will work, and you can use IMPORTRANGE formulas that reference the URL-containing cells on the "splash sheet."

[image]

As for the OP's original question, I came here seeking an answer to the same problem, and after more research have realized that we are attempting the impossible here. No way to do this an ARRAYFORMULA. No way around writing formulas that reference *every single cell* a document's URL may go into.

Problem is you can't make arrays of arrays in spreadsheets; that would involve multiple dimensions, and the medium is inherently two-dimensional. This is what people use databases for.

Comment: But using IMPORTRANGE in this interim way will still replicate the entire data from another place into the current file, which means the whole point of keeping data in other places (to circumvent the 5 million row limit) is lost. Yes?

Comment: There are many other reasons to keep data in multiple documents and have multiple documents that reference them.

Comment: Also, IMPORTRANGE does not replicate all the data from the source doc; it only imports the data you specify. What I am doing here is importing only a single cell from each source document, not for the sake of importing that info, but to establish that the one doc may import data from the source docs.

Answer (score 0):

> **TLDR**: If I understand your intention correctly when you say you would like to see
> `=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(B2:B4,C2:C4))`, I believe you can make that
> happen using the following.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(
  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B2:B4), COLUMN(B2:B4)),
  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C2:C4), COLUMN(C2:C4))
)
```

### Breakdown

1. Use **IMPORTRANGE** with **INDIRECT** to create ranges inside **ARRAYFORMULA**
2. Call **INDIRECT** with the **ADDRESS** function
3. Call **ADDRESS** with the **ROW** and **COLUMN** functions *since they take ranges via ARRAYFORMULA*

### using IMPORTRANGE with INDIRECT

*IMPORTRANGE*'s two parameters are the spreadsheet url *stored in B2:B4 for this example* and the range (e.g. sheet!A1:B2) *stored in C2:C4*.

Since *IMPORTRANGE* doesn't take a range reference directly as you mentioned, you'll need to build it for each row with *ARRAYFORMULA* using the *INDIRECT* function.

**[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)** can be used to compose a cell reference using A1 notation, for instance

```
=IMPORTRANGE(INDIRECT("B" & 2), INDIRECT("C" & 2))
```

will produce the same result as

```
=IMPORTRANGE(B2, C2)
```

Since this produces the same result, we now just have to find a way to make *INDIRECT* work with *ARRAYFORMULA*

### Use ADDRESS to build the parameters for INDIRECT

Next you want to use *ADDRESS* to build the A1 reference for *INDIRECT*.  For the current purposes, **[ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)** takes a numerical value for row and column as parameters

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2))
```

will produce the same result as

```
=INDIRECT("B" & 2)
```

Since these two are interchangeable, now we just need to find a way to get the numerical row and column values out of *ARRAYFORMULA*.

### Call ADDRESS using the  ROW and COLUMN functions

From there, you can get the row and column indexes from standard A1 notation using the **[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)** and **[COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en)** functions.  While this may seem like we're pointlessly going in circles, the difference now is that *ROW* and *COLUMN* perform as expected with the ranges provided by *ARRAYFORMULA*.  So given that *ADDRESS* will return **$B$2** using using either method below

```
=ADDRESS(2,2)
```

or

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B2),COLUMN(B2))
```

we now know that

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(ROW(B2:B4),COLUMN(B2:B4)))
```

will produce the following array of addresses

```
{ $B$2; $B$3; $B$4 }
```

### Final Assembly

So when we put this all together, we get

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(
  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B2:B4), COLUMN(B2:B4)),
  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C2:C4), COLUMN(C2:C4))
)
```

- where `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B2:B4), COLUMN(B2:B4))` is more or less interchangeable with what you might expect from `B2:B4` inside *ARRAYFORMULA* and represents the url parameter
- and `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C2:C4), COLUMN(C2:C4))` is roughly interchangeable with what you might expect from `C2:C4` inside *ARRAYFORMULA* and represents the range parameter.

### Suggestions on organization

I recommend using the indentation (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Enter</kbd> *to create a new line* ) above along with your indentation of choice to keep it easier to read.  In the end it's just a bit more syntactic sugar and if spaces are used well it shouldn't be much harder to understand and make changes to 6 months later.

> **RE: Permissions** - as mentioned by Atiq Zabinski, just placing a simple
> IMPORTRANGE("http:/xxxx", "A1") somewhere on the sheet will provide a
> means to know if the sheet is connected or not and the error message
> should give you a context menu for connecting the sheet.  You'll might
> want to stay away from error handling in these scenarios as it will
> slow down the process of connecting the sheets.