# Google sheets: Arrayformula with importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to work with combined arrangeformula and importrange formulas. I want that from spreadsheet1:[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsG88.jpg) P4 value would be taken to spreadsheet2 C3 cell: [Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCvRd.jpg) and only when i add new link to column "L" it will put automatic value at C4. So i want to use arrangeformula so it will work on whole column, but i want to fix that from all the links i add it would take same "P4" value. Possible?

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eMD5S-C3KCuubGJTz9Z5aMTUjZaaOY5l?usp=sharing Here is link for both spreadsheets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution. See [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504050/using-importrange-as-an-array-formula/41513412#41513412) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508675/arrayformula-with-importrange/47515737#47515737)

All you can is

```
={IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE($L3;"Lapas1!A2");"");
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE($L4;"Lapas1!A2");"");
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE($L5;"Lapas1!A2");"");
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE($L6;"Lapas1!A2");"")}
```

as many times as you wish

Comment: It's not good, i need that Spreadsheet2 cells "C3","C4","C5" would have same "P4" cell value only from different spreadsheet according to link on "L" column. In this existing case, "C3","C4","C5" should show same value "92". Hope you understand.

Comment: ok, try the modification (i can't test since i have only one id of source)

Comment: I created one more spreadsheet to have different values of P4:X4 and also different A2 value. Added that spreadsheet link L column. You can now check how it works

Comment: thx, I will have a look soon, I do not have yet the solution

Comment: Thank You very much for your effort, we will use your suggestions! :)